# Clarification of a result in Isaacs's Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was revisiting group theory in detail and reading Isaacs's Finite Group Theory book in my own time. I need a little clarification on one result. Any help will be really appreciated. This is  Corollary 1.46. on page 43 (just before the Problems 1G). The screenshot of the result (along with the proof) is below.

[image]

> My question is by "not a nonabelian simple group" should one prove that $G$ is not simple and also $G$ is abelian? Because in the proof I think it is only proved that $G$ is not simple.

Sorry if I missed something, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From a purely linguistic point of view, I cannot see any possible ambiguity in "not a nonabelian simple group". If I say that the object that I holding is not a green apple, this means that it must be either not green or not an apple or both. For example, it could be a green ball or a red apple or a black pen. By default you have to assume that things mean exactly what they say, provided that it makes sense at all!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Yes. Things are clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof shows that $G$ contains a nontrivial abelian normal subgroup $M$.

Now, if $G$ is simple, then the only possibility is that $G=M$, and hence that $G$ is abelian. So $G$ cannot be simultaneously simple and nonabelian.

Comment: Thanks. So the claim "not a nonabelian simple group" means that "cannot be simultaneously simple and nonabelian". This is what I missed.